# Reading an Avro file from scala

Tags: scala, avro

I'm trying to read an avro file using scala.

I've extracted the file's schema using avro-tools and saved it to a file, I then try to read it using the following code:

```
 val zibi= scala.io.Source.fromFile("/home/wasabi/schema").mkString
 val schema_obj =  new Schema.Parser
 val schema2 = schema_obj.parse(zibi)
 val READER2 = new GenericDatumReader[GenericRecord](schema2)
 val myFile = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/tmp/check/CMRF_80_1442744555901-1_1_2_1_1_1_4_10_1.avro"))

 val datum = READER2.read(null, DecoderFactory.defaultFactory.createBinaryDecoder(myFile,null))
```

But I keep hitting IOExceptions as such:

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid int encoding
        at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readInt(BinaryDecoder.java:145)
        at org.apache.avro.io.ValidatingDecoder.readInt(ValidatingDecoder.java:83)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readInt(GenericDatumReader.java:444)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:159)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:193)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:183)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:151)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readArray(GenericDatumReader.java:219)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:193)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:183)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:151)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:142)
```

When I'm reading the file through avro-tools it reads just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the following: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1650 (it seems very similar to your issue and suggested solution might work for you.)

Comment: Hi,
Yes I saw it. I'm not converting to or from string so I don't think it's relevant (unless readAllBytes has some kind of encoding configuration). Just to make sure I tried reading it as a string with the suggested encoding but that failed too.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using a `DataFileReader` instead of using a `BinaryDecoder`.

While Encoder/Decoders are used for writing and reading raw avros, I suspect that they are choking on the header info found in avro datafiles.

```
import org.apache.avro.generic.{ GenericDatumReader, GenericRecord }
import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader

val zibi= scala.io.Source.fromFile("/home/wasabi/schema").mkString
val schema_obj =  new Schema.Parser
val schema2 = schema_obj.parse(zibi)
val READER2 = new GenericDatumReader[GenericRecord](schema2)

val myFile = new File("/tmp/check/CMRF_80_1442744555901-1_1_2_1_1_1_4_10_1.avro")
val dataFileReader = new DataFileReader[GenericRecord](myFile, READER2)
val datum = dataFileReader.next()
```